# How to denote a user as a "system account"?

Tags: 7, users, services

In the Unix world, there are "user accounts" for humans to use, and there are "system accounts" for software to use.

On a Drupal site, I have a couple of *system accounts* intended for use by `services.module` API calls.

I'd like these accounts to be able to log in via the services API (obviously), but I would like to block these accounts from being used to log in via the standard `user_login` form.  I'd also like to prevent these accounts from showing up in standard "active user" lists, such as the "Who's online" block.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 4):

Have you had a look at using the API key authentication? This will enable you to login effectively without using a username + password combo.

See http://drupal.org/node/762092 for more information

Comment: Thanks, @wiifm.  I am already using API key authentication, though.  Unless I'm mistaken, when using API key authentication, operations are still performed by the anonymous user by default, and thus it's still necessary to log in with standard user credentials to perform most operations (since I wouldn't want to, for example, enable all anonymous users to post nodes).

Answer (score 1):

I will reply referring to what the [Project issue tracking](http://drupal.org/project/project_issue) module does.

The *Project issue tracking* module changes the status of the issue reports that have been marked as fixed for two weeks to "closed (fixed)"; while doing that, it adds a comment that result posted by the "System Message" user (the module has a setting that allows to change that user to any other existing user), as it is visible in [this comment](http://drupal.org/node/1045714#comment-4145456).

To create such comments, the module uses the function `user_load()` (see the function [_project_issue_followup_get_user()](http://drupalcode.org/project/project_issue.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/master:/project_issue.module)), changes the content of the global variable `$user`, does its task, and then changes back the value of the global variable. The full operation is started during the CRON tasks (see the [_project_issue_cron()](http://drupalcode.org/project/project_issue.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/master:/includes/cron.inc) function, which invokes `project_issue_auto_close()`, which invokes [project_issue_add_auto_followup()](http://drupalcode.org/project/project_issue.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/master:/project_issue.module), which invokes `project_issue_add_followup()`).

In any of these operations, the "System Message" user appears in the list of the users who recently logged in, or in the list of the online users.
It doesn't appear in the "Who's online" block because the hook that outputs that block (user_block()) uses `SELECT uid, name FROM {users} WHERE status != 0 AND access != 0 ORDER BY created DESC` as SQL query to get the list of online user; as the "System Message" user is never used from a real user to log in, the `access` field always contain `0`.
If there would be a module that changes that database field to something different, it is enough to set it to 0 to avoid such system users are listed as online users.

If those user accounts you created to be used by a module have a password that is difficult to discover, the fact somebody could use those user accounts to log in should not be a problem if the password is only known by you.
If somebody else knows the password (or somebody is able to change the password associated with the user account), and you want to avoid they use one of the system accounts to log in (considering the user accounts could have permissions that are not assigned to other users as it happens on Drupal.org, which uses some "system users" for some purposes), then you can implement `hook_form_user_login()` to add a form validation handler to the form created by [user_login()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_login/6), adding the code that verifies if the username passed through the form is one associated with one of the user accounts you don't want to be used to log in.

To notice that it is not necessary to pass any password to `user_load()`; the password is only passed to the function when a user is logging in, and Drupal needs to verify that the user entered the correct password. The suggestion of thsutton to modify the content of the password field with something that is not a MD5 checksum (i.e. a string that doesn't have 32 characters, or that contains characters not present in a MD5 checksum) is valid, if you never use the "system user" to log in.
If you use the user to log in, then the user will appear in the list of the recently logged in users; if you want to avoid this, you need to reset the access field to 0.

Comment: "Have a password that is difficult to discover."Or you could use something that is definitely not a valid password (i.e. not a valid MD5 checksum)